# php json check validation / sanitise

Tags: php, json, validation

I have read about this and people ask this a bit too often.

lets say u have a input

```
$_POST['json_txt'] = "{
  bar:'value 1',
  foo:{
    baz:'value 2',
    fuz:'value 3'
  }
}";
```

We can validate this input using the php function `json_last_error ();`

**Q 1** = Shouldn't there be another option where we can sanitise this json object?

**Q2**  = Also is the `json_last_error();` the absolute way to correctly validate the input and save it to a db (mysql)?

Comment: You could also check if `json_decode` returns null, meaning it's invalid.

Comment: nice one, just realised that `json_last_error ();` only works on `php 5 >=5.3.0`

Comment: I see you already have your answer, but you don't need to worry about sanitizing JSON on the PHP side the same way you do on the JS side. On the JS side, if you just `eval()` (which you shouldn't be doing anyway) the string, and it contains something malicious, it will be `eval()`ed. PHP actually deserializes the string into a structure (if it can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saving the entire JSON object to the database, or individual parts?
You can sanitize a variable (either one from the decoded JSON object or the JSON object itself) with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before inserting it into the database.

Comment: of course i have done that :) but what i meant is to check that there are no weird characters and things like that or do we just use `regex` so we only allow valid and the characters you expect. also yes, i am putting the json object as a whole :)

Comment: So you need to know whether the object is a valid JSON object? You can test that with the return vanlue of json_decode.